# How to mask the largest object of one kind in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, object

**Want to fetch only the largest Object of each kind.**
Here, the aim is to visualize only RGB objects one of each kind. But it is fetching objects too. I found the best way of detecting the largest object by biggest contour but other items of similar kind are also show here i want to ignore them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Webcamera no 0 is used to capture the frames
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#print(cv2.__version__)
# This drives the program into an infinite loop.
while(1):
    # Captures the live stream frame-by-frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    blurred_frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(5,5),100)
    # Converts images from BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #print(hsv)
    lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
    upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
    lower_green = np.array([65,60,60])
    upper_green = np.array([80,255,255])
    lower_blue = np.array([100,150,0])
    upper_blue = np.array([140,255,255])

    # Here we are defining range of bluecolor in HSV
    # This creates a mask of blue coloured
    # objects found in the frame.
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=3)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=5)
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    mask1 = cv2.erode(mask1, None, iterations=3)
    mask1 = cv2.dilate(mask1, None, iterations=5)
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask2 = cv2.erode(mask2, None, iterations=3)
    mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask2, None, iterations=5)
    #ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours2, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #print(contours)
    mask_rg=cv2.bitwise_or(mask,mask1)
    mask_res=cv2.bitwise_or(mask2,mask_rg)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask_res)
    #cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 3)
    if len(contours)!=0:
        contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
        biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
        for c in contours:
            area=cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area>50:
                cv2.drawContours(res, biggest_contour,-5, (0,0,255), 10)
    if len(contours1)!=0:
        contour_sizes1 = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours1]
        biggest_contour1 = max(contour_sizes1, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
        for c in contours1:
            area=cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area>50:
                cv2.drawContours(res, biggest_contour1,-5, (0,255,0), 10)
    if len(contours2)!=0:
        contour_sizes2 = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours2]
        biggest_contour2 = max(contour_sizes2, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]
        for c in contours1:
            area=cv2.contourArea(c)
            if area>50:
                cv2.drawContours(res, biggest_contour2,-5, (255,0,0), 10)
        # The bitwise and of the frame and mask is done so
        # that only the blue coloured objects are highlighted
        # and stored in res

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    #cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    # This displays the frame, mask
    # and res which we created in 3 separate windows.
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

# Destroys all of the HighGUI windows.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# release the captured frame
cap.release()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXKE0.png)
I don't want 2 blue color objects only one should be seen which is detected by contours.
Please help me out.

Comment: Can you attach sample input frame and expected output?

Comment: attach input frame

Comment: Its there in the link **enter image description here**